# For loop to iterate through user input to calculate cost?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, iteration

I'm working in Java. So what I'm trying to do is, take the user input from subscriberPackage

```
public static String subscriberPackage() { //Method to get the customers name
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nPlease choose a package the customer would like:");
        System.out.println("Enter Bronze, Silver or Gold to select a package.");
        String subscriptionPackage = sc.nextLine(); //Get subscription package from the user
        while (!(subscriptionPackage.equalsIgnoreCase("Bronze") || subscriptionPackage.equalsIgnoreCase("Silver") || subscriptionPackage.equalsIgnoreCase("Gold"))) {

            System.err.println("This is not a valid package!");
            System.err.println("Please try again!");
            System.out.println("Please choose a package the customer would like:");
            System.out.println("Bronze, Silver or Gold.");
            subscriptionPackage = sc.nextLine();
            //If the package entered is not Bronze, Silver or Gold, the user is asked to re-enter till the while condition is  met

        }
        return subscriptionPackage; //Returns the subscription package to the newSubscription method
    }
```

and subscriberDuration

```
 public static int subscriberDuration() { //Method to get the subscription duration
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nPlease choose the subscription duration");
        System.out.println("It must be either 1, 3, 6 or 12 months.");
        System.out.println("Please now enter the subscription duration the customer would like");
        int subscriptionDuration = sc.nextInt(); //Get the subscription duration from the user


        while (subscriptionDuration != 1 && subscriptionDuration != 3 && subscriptionDuration != 6 && subscriptionDuration != 12) {
            System.err.println("This is not a valid duration, please try again!");
            System.err.println("It must be either 1, 3, 6 or 12 months.");
            subscriptionDuration = sc.nextInt();
            //If the duration entered is not 1, 3, 6 or 12, the user is asked to re-enter till the while condition is  met

        }
        return subscriptionDuration; //Returns the subscription duration to the newSubscription method
    }
```

and calculate a cost in subscriberBill.

```
private static int subscriberBill(String subscriptionPackage, int subscriptionDuration) {

        int subscriptionCost = 0;
        int[] subsBronzePackageCosts = new int[1000];
        subsBronzePackageCosts[0] = 600;
        subsBronzePackageCosts[1] = 500;
        subsBronzePackageCosts[2] = 400;
        subsBronzePackageCosts[3] = 300;
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i+=3){
            if (subscriptionPackage.equals(subscriptionPackage) && (subscriptionDuration == subscriptionDuration)) {
                subscriptionCost = (subsBronzePackageCosts[i] + i + count);
                count++;
                System.out.println("\nThe cost of this subscription is: " + subscriptionCost);

                return subscriptionCost;


            }
        }
        return subscriptionCost;
    }
}
```

I have managed to pass through this information and started adding the costs of the Bronze tier subscriptionPackage. I have done this using an array:

```
int[] subsBronzePackageCosts = new int[1000];
        subsBronzePackageCosts[0] = 600;
        subsBronzePackageCosts[1] = 500;
        subsBronzePackageCosts[2] = 400;
        subsBronzePackageCosts[3] = 300;
```

I'm trying to loop through said array so that for example, a user has set the duration as 3, it'll iterate using the for loop through my array and set `subscriptionCost` to the appropriate value. In this instance, that being 400.

The part I'm stuck with, is iterating through the array with the for loop. I have it so it's only adding + 1 and reporting 500 every time. I did have a solution working for if else statements for each different package type and duration, but obviously, this isn't ideal practice and causes repetitive code, which I'm trying to avoid.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: To add a bit more context. I have three tiers of subscriptionPackage to work with: Bronze, Silver and Gold.
All of these packages have different pricings and the pricings change with the length of subscriptionDuration that the user enters.

The packages/pricings are:
Bronze prices are 600 for 1 month, 500 for 3 months, 400 for 6 months and 300 for 12 months.

Silver prices are 800 for 1 month, 700 for 3 months, 600 for 6 months and 500 for 12 months.

Gold prices are 999 for 1 month, 899 for 3 months, 799 for 6 months and 699 for 12 months.

Comment: Is using an Array required for some reason? You'd probably be better off using a `Map<Integer,Integer>` or `Map<SubscriptionDuration,Integer>`.  There isn't a friendly way to convert [1,3,6,12] into [0,1,2,3] (without your previous if statement). If you had to use an Array, you'd want to use something like `SubscriptionCosts[]` where you could match `SubscriptionCost.months`.

Comment: So, I think it'd be more ideal if I did, yes. Because I have to also do this for a Silver and Gold tier, both of which have different costs which I'll set into an array also. My previous if else statmenets were very long in the tooth and repetetive. 

Silver prices are 800 for 1 month, 700 for 3 months, 600 for 6 months and 500 for 12 months.

Gold prices are 999 for 1 month, 899 for 3 months, 799 for 6 months and 699 for 12 months.

So I had basically a subsGoldPackage and a subsSilverPackage array and if else statmements to match, all inside the same method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code here is a bit of a mess to look at.  But I guess I would point you to the logic in your if statement ...

subscriptionPackage.equals(subscriptionPackage) ... this is always true, right?  So you can just delete this.

subscriptionDuraction == suscriptionDuration ... thius is also always true, right?  So your whole if statement disappears.

So this if statement ALWAYS evaluates to true, which means you will always hit the return statement in the if block, with i=1, and in your array, [1] = 500.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What I was trying to achieve, was so that if a user enters a Bronze Subscription Package, it'll take that as well as the duration they enter (1, 3, 6 or 12) and give a cost to that. 

I.e. they enter a Brone Package and enter a 3 month during. The cost needs to be set to 400. I need to do this for Bronze, Silver and Gold; all of which have different pricing for each tier. Removing the if statement, it just always returns 500, no matter the duration length.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest attempting to work with classes, for example:

```
// Going this far could be up for debate
public enum SubscriptionType { GOLD, SILVER, BRONZE }
public enum SubscriptionDuration { MONTHLY, QUARTERLY, BI_ANNUALLY, ANNUALLY }
```

```
public class SubscriptionFee {
  SubscriptionType type;         // Replace with String
  SubscriptionDuration duration; // Replace with Integer
  int cost;
}
```

Both `type` and `duration` are up for debate if you'd rather use `String` and `Integer` respectively.

You can try to implement these in your current code and see if it's easier to loop through all the options comparing:

- subscriptionFee.type
- subscriptionFee.duration

to the information you've collected from the "user".